# Can I make the name of a new object variable in c#?

Tags: c#

For example:

```
car Audi = new car();
```

Is it possible to something like this:

```
string name = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Name of new car?", "Add car");
car name = new car();
```

Sorry if this is a stupid or duplicate question.

Comment: yes, it is a stupid question, but at least you know it :-) But it is a common question, so don't feel bad :-) So it isn't really a stupid question... let's say that it is a common stepping stone :-) A rite of passage.

Comment: But is it possible? I'm still not that adept with programming and currently making a program where I want to use something like this.

Comment: No you can't. If it were possible, how would you access it?

Comment: I would put it as a new line for a dropdownbox everytime in my form application and then make it so that the one your accessing is the one you've selected in the dropdownlist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. In C# variables must be known at compile time, together with their names...

What you can do is have a collection where to put all your cars... Like:

```
var allmycars = new Dictionary<string, Car>();

string name = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Name of new car?", "Add car");

car mycar = new car();
allmycars.Add(name, mycar);
```

then you can:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, car> onecar in allmycars)
{
    string name2 = onecar.Key;
    car car2 = onecar.Value;

    Console.WriteLine(name2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot do that. But you can use a different data structure for something similar.

Use `Dictionary`

```
Dictionary<string, car> dictionary = new Dictionary<string,car>();
if(!dictionary.ContainsKey(name))
{
     dictionary.Add(name, new car());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible as variable names are converted to addresses in memory whenever you compile the program.

Since you're trying to name the variable after you compiled the program during runtime, it wouldn't make a difference since it's no longer a human readable name.

Answer (score -2):

The only way I can think of doing it is a C# version of

```
car = Car() //basically Python way of initializing car

del car

car = Thing()
```

Comment: You need to delete the variable from memory. May take a few imports